# Error when trying to import data into Rstudio: namespace "lifecycle" 0.2.0 is being loaded but >= 1.0.0 is required

Tags: r, excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxegE.png)
Hi I have been trying to import by data from an excel file into Rstudio. I usually just press the import dataset button in the environment pane. It lets me browse and select my file I want to import and then I get this error message popping up (see photo).

I have tried reinstalling R, Rstudio and Rtools. I reinstalled all packages including lifecycle and updated all packages as well. I have also tried importing a text file and naming the excel file as an .cvs, neither worked.
Couldn't find any similar problems as this when googling.
Can someone please help me?

**Update:** I have been able to now import data in a text file instead of excel. But now the dplyr package isn't working. I'm getting this message in the console when I run library(dyplr):

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
namespace ‘lifecycle’ 0.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.1 is required
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 4.0.5

I have installed and updated the dyplr package.
Anyone have any answers to this problem?

Comment: You need to update all installed packages, possibly you also need to update R. You seem to have installed a really (several years) old version of the lifecycle package.

Comment: @Roland I have tried to install a newer version of lifecycle multiple times by install.packages("lifecycle"). I have also have updated all packages before but I'll try one more time.

Comment: @Roland I tried updating all packages again but the error is still popping up.

Comment: I‘m pretty sure you need to update R. You seem to be using a heavily outdated version.